# Upload compressed image file to Moodle server

Tags: php, ajax, compression, moodle, moodle-api

I want to upload a compressed image file to moodle server. I'm using below script to append the compressed image file to an existing form.

```
var currentForm = event.target.form;
var newForm = new FormData(currentForm);
newForm.append("testmoodle", compressedBlobFile, "testmoodle.jpg");
```

but when I submit the request the file data return the empty values.

```
[testmoodle] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 4
        [size] => 0
    )
```

This blob image upload is working in new(separate) form:

```
function uploadToServer (blobData) {
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', blobData);
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8888/server.php",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: function (res) {
        alert("Compressed file successfully uploaded", JSON.stringify(res));
      },
      error: function(err){
        alert("Something went wrong",JSON.stringify(err));
      }
  });
}
```

Is there any alternative way to send the blob image files to moodle server using the existing form in moodle server?
I want to compress the file in moodle server. I'm using the [this compression plug to compressed file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-image-compression)

[image: Moodle filepicker form]

Comment: What is the `enctype` of your form set to?

Comment: @CBroe enctype="multipart/form-data"